# react-chartist displays solid black

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chartist.js, react-chartist

I'm using chartlist. http://fraserxu.me/react-chartist/

The data is not displaying correctly. The data is displaying like this:

[image]

When according to the docs it should be displaying like this:

[image]

Here is the code per the docs:
http://fraserxu.me/react-chartist/

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChartistGraph from "react-chartist";



class PreBuy extends Component {


    render() {


        var simpleLineChartData = {
            labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            series: [
                [12, 9, 7, 8, 5],
                [2, 1, 3.5, 7, 3],
                [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
            ]
        }

        let style = {
            height: 400,
            position: "relative",
            top: 300
        }

        return (

            <section>
            <div style={style}>
                  <ChartistGraph data={simpleLineChartData} type={'Line'} />

            </div>




          </section>

        )

    }
}


export default PreBuy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include `css` from bower CDN or import it to the project.

Look at [documentation](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html)

*e.g.*
Include to your `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
```

Comment: I am using create-react-app and the following works. Above my react component I did:  import './reactChartlist.css'; // Import regular stylesheet ;

Comment: Here is the [source](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/tree/master/dist) to download  `css` or `scss` you would like to use

Comment: Yes, I copied the CSS source into the file I mentioned above. Thanks!

Comment: @William i love you mate . You saved my day !